# Entity Framework 6 - Configuration mapping from multiple tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have two tables which looks like below:

http://s30.postimg.org/i3u7pmpz5/baza.png

I created models looks like below:

```
public class DomainUser : User
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Sid { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public virtual DomainPhone Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual DomainEmail Email { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Modified { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create DomainUser object with data from table DomainUser and User.
Here is a sample query which we want to generate by EF:

```
 select  [Extent1].[Id] as [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Login] as [Login], 
        [Extent2].[Guid] as [Guid], 
        [Extent2].[Sid] as [Sid], 
        [Extent2].[Title] as [Title], 
        [Extent2].[Company] as [Company], 
        [Extent2].[Department] as [Department], 
        [Extent2].[Office] as [Office] 
from    [dbo].[User] as [Extent1] inner join [dbo].[DomainUser] as [Extent2] on [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: In your class `DomainUser` inherits from `User` so you don't need to join anything together.

Comment: I'm still don't know how to do this, could you give me example of EF context configuration?

Comment: There isn't really any config to do, what does your context look like now?